# Al llamar la funcion con el autorization no envia la consulta

Tags: fetch

```
    gameRegister: async (game)=>{
    let store = getStore();
      try {
        let response = await fetch(`${store.urlBase}/api/game`, {
          method: 'POST',
          mode: 'no-cors',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer  ${store.token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(game)
        });
        
        console.log(response)
        if (response.ok){
          return true;

        }
        return false;
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
      
    }
  },
```

*este es la función que hace el fetch retorna 401 aun y cuando el token es valido el response tampoco devuelve la url.

Comment: El problema es que al ponerle mode `no-cors` estás limitando los headers a una pequeña cantidad que es considerada "segura" para esos casos. Tanto el `'Content-Type':'application/json'` y el `Authorization` que especificas, no son validos en modo `no-cors`, por eso esas cabeceras seguramente no se están incluyendo en el request real, y de ahi el error 401 (Como si no estuvieras mandando header de `Authorization`)

Comment: De igual manera, usar el modo `no-cors` retornara un "Respuesta Opaca (Opaque response)", lo que hará que basicamente no puedas acceder a la respuesta